# Moving directory across drives, using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to move a folder and its subfiles from `C:\` to `D:\` by using batch file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to move folders across drives. This kind of "move" is simply a copy followed by a deletion. So you could do:

```
xcopy c:\example d:\example /S /E
rmdir /S c:\example
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can do this process this way I want to do this by using less memory. Because in some situations the memory can be not enough. So I am looking for direct moving by not using extra memory.

Comment: Did you read the rest of my answer? You cannot "move directly" a folder across drives. It has to be a copy followed by a deletion operation. But I wonder on what system you are working on if there's not enough memory to run a simple DOS command.

Comment: I am working on Windows. Now, I understood your answer. I will use other ways.
Thank you,

Comment: I want to ask a question about moving a directory and it's subdirectory,
I can move all of subfolders recursively by using this command line: "FOR /R C:\Temp %%i IN (*.*) DO MOVE "%%i" D:" but, it moves only .txt files but I want to move all subdirectories and subfolders, not only .txt files. Are there any way to do this?

Comment: @aprogrammer, you should post a second question, so that you can get more feedback. But, in general BATCH is not a very good programming language, you cannot do very complex things with it. Have you considered using an alternative like [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)? If you can choose the language, I strongly recommend that one.

Comment: I am new about BATCH and I am an intern so I am researching about BATCH but I am going to research about Autohotkey too. Thanks for your answer.