# require a batch file to copy from network drive to my local system

Tags: networking, batch-file, copy, directory

I have a network drive as diwakar(\192.168.204.45) . i want to copy files from this network drive to c:\users\ How to write a batch file for this work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving directory across drives, using batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027928/moving-directory-across-drives-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this - it is designed to map the drive using your credentials and then robocopy can mirror the drive to the `"c:\users\peter\network drive"` folder.

Be careful: Mirroring is a very powerful tool which will delete files if you aren't careful with the target folder name.

```
@echo off
net use z: "\\192.168.204.45\share" /user:yourname
if exist "z:\" robocopy "z:\" "c:\users\peter\network drive" /mir
```

Comment: finally i got the solution.    xcopy /e \\192.168.204.45\diwakar\*.* "c:\users\"

Comment: That command line will skip certain files - hidden etc.  It also doesn't use username and password so you must have sufficient access.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:   xcopy /e \192.168.204.45\diwakar*.* "c:\users\" it will copy every thing present from share drive and move into the destination folder.